# Website functionality automatically start and stop working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, web

Recently I got a project where I had to make some changes in a Wordpress website with some customized theme (Besocial + BBpress) and custom coding. Now, I have almost done all changes but there is a strange bug/error where login and register functionality sometimes work as intended and sometimes it doesn't. Also, after login, user has to be redirected to a News Feed (much like Facebook) but that too sometimes work and sometimes doesn't. I am not being able to find what is the error or bug. Can you please suggest something to make my process easier? The project is already delayed for 2 weeks.

Thanks, any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

a)open website in private window, see if issue is still their, if not than delete browser cookies.

b)Deactivate plugins and check the issue.

c)Check by changing the theme.

d)Reset Permalinks

e)check your .htaccess

By doing these thing you will know from where issue is coming.